# Sorting XML file based on XML nodes & XML comments using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need help in sorting an XML file based on xml nodes and ONE more thing is i have to place their comment tags corresponding to that node.

For Example: Input XML File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- catalog main -->
<catalog>
 <!-- first book id -->
 <book id="bk101">
  <!-- author name 1 -->
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <!-- title name 1 -->
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <!-- price 1 -->
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <Book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
 </Book>


 <!-- languages -->
 <Languages>
  <!-- java comment -->
  <java>Galos, Mike</java>
  <c>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</c>
  <!-- dotnet comment -->
  <dotnet>Computer</dotnet>
  <!-- description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
 </Languages>

 <!-- ABC book -->
 <ABC>
  <!-- ABC author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
  <!-- ABC genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <!-- ABC description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
 </ABC>
 <!-- ABC1 book -->
 <abc1>
  <!-- ABC1 author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
  <!-- ABC1 genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <!-- ABC1 description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
 </abc1>
</catalog>
```

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT XML FILE SHOULD BE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- catalog main -->
<catalog>
 <!-- ABC book -->
 <ABC>
  <!-- ABC author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <!-- ABC description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
  <!-- ABC genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
 </ABC>
 <!-- ABC1 book -->
 <abc1>
  <!-- ABC1 author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <!-- ABC1 description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
  <!-- ABC1 genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
 </abc1>
 <!-- first book id -->
 <book id="bk101">
  <!-- author name 1 -->
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <!-- price 1 -->
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <!-- title name 1 -->
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
 </book>
 <Book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
 </Book>
 <!-- languages -->
 <Languages>
  <c>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</c>
  <!-- description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
  <!-- dotnet comment -->
  <dotnet>Computer</dotnet>
  <!-- java comment -->
  <java>Galos, Mike</java>
 </Languages>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have resolved this issue with an additional implementation.. 
Below is the new code:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::node()[1]/self::comment()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                <xsl:sort select="@*"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can any one suggest in the above code by adding a new line of code which make sorting with attribute name?

Comment: sorting preference order is based on 
1. node
2. attribute name
3. attribute value

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::node()[1]/self::comment()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<!-- catalog main -->
<catalog>
    <!-- ABC book -->
    <ABC>
        <!-- ABC author -->
        <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
        <!-- ABC description -->
        <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
        <!-- ABC genre -->
        <genre1>Computer</genre1>
        <price1>49.95</price1>
        <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
        <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
    </ABC>
    <!-- ABC1 book -->
    <abc1>
        <!-- ABC1 author -->
        <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
        <!-- ABC1 description -->
        <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
        <!-- ABC1 genre -->
        <genre1>Computer</genre1>
        <price1>49.95</price1>
        <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
        <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
    </abc1>
    <!-- first book id -->
    <book id="bk101">
        <!-- author name 1 -->
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <!-- price 1 -->
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <!-- title name 1 -->
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    </book>
    <Book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.</description>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    </Book>
    <!-- languages -->
    <Languages>
        <c>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</c>
        <!-- description -->
        <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
        <!-- dotnet comment -->
        <dotnet>Computer</dotnet>
        <!-- java comment -->
        <java>Galos, Mike</java>
    </Languages>
</catalog>
```