# Sorting XML file based on XML nodes & XML comment tags using XSLT

Tags: xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting XML file based on XML nodes & XML comments using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124373/sorting-xml-file-based-on-xml-nodes-xml-comments-using-xslt)

Hi All,

I need help in sorting an XML file based on xml nodes and ONE more thing is i have to place their comment tags corresponding to that node.

For Example: Input XML File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- catalog main -->
<catalog>
 <!-- first book id -->
 <book id="bk101">
  <!-- author name 1 -->
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <!-- title name 1 -->
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <!-- price 1 -->
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <Book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
 </Book>


 <!-- languages -->
 <Languages>
  <!-- java comment -->
  <java>Galos, Mike</java>
  <c>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</c>
  <!-- dotnet comment -->
  <dotnet>Computer</dotnet>
  <!-- description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
 </Languages>

 <!-- ABC book -->
 <ABC>
  <!-- ABC author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
  <!-- ABC genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <!-- ABC description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
 </ABC>
 <!-- ABC1 book -->
 <abc1>
  <!-- ABC1 author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
  <!-- ABC1 genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <!-- ABC1 description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
 </abc1>
</catalog>
```

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT XML FILE SHOULD BE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- catalog main -->
<catalog>
 <!-- ABC book -->
 <ABC>
  <!-- ABC author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <!-- ABC description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
  <!-- ABC genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
 </ABC>
 <!-- ABC1 book -->
 <abc1>
  <!-- ABC1 author -->
  <author1>Galos, Mike</author1>
  <!-- ABC1 description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
  <!-- ABC1 genre -->
  <genre1>Computer</genre1>
  <price1>49.95</price1>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <title1>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title1>
 </abc1>
 <!-- first book id -->
 <book id="bk101">
  <!-- author name 1 -->
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <!-- price 1 -->
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <!-- title name 1 -->
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
 </book>
 <Book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
 </Book>
 <!-- languages -->
 <Languages>
  <c>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</c>
  <!-- description -->
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
  <!-- dotnet comment -->
  <dotnet>Computer</dotnet>
  <!-- java comment -->
  <java>Galos, Mike</java>
 </Languages>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Please **do not** post the same exact question again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124373/sorting-xml-file-based-on-xml-nodes-xml-comments-using-xslt

Comment: I voted to `C L O S E`  this as an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124373/sorting-xml-file-based-on-xml-nodes-xml-comments-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

This Question is similar to what i posted in another Question..

below is the url:

[Sorting XML file based on XML nodes & XML comments using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124373/sorting-xml-file-based-on-xml-nodes-xml-comments-using-xslt)